# Can you modify a uniform from within the shader? If so. how?

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-shader

So I wanted to store all my meshes in one large VBO. The problem is, how do you do have just one draw call, but let every mesh have its own model to world matrix?

My idea was to submit an array of matrices to a uniform before drawing. In the VBO I would make the color of every first vertex of a mesh negative (So I'd be using the signing bit to check whether a vertex was the first of a mesh).

Okay, so I can detect when a new mesh has started and I have an array of matrices ready and probably a uniform called 'index'. But how do I increase this index by one every time I encounter a new mesh?

Can you modify a uniform from within the shader? If so, how?

Comment: That's not how a graphics card works. Look up Instancing.

Comment: I know what instancing is. The problem is, I have different meshes in one VBO.

Comment: You could add an ID to the vertex attributes and look up the world matrix based on the ID.

Comment: As far as I know, uniforms are not meant to be changed, like const variables. Why don't you make a seperate VBO for each mesh? wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: Yes, it would. But it would also mean that I'll have lots and lost of small VBOs , which I don't think is a good idea. An ID would maybe be the best way to go.

Comment: One way of doing it is to have a second VBO containing the transforms, including it in the VA with a per-instance offset.

Comment: Is that possible with different meshes in the VBO? (I'm kind of an openGL newbie)

Comment: Yes.  And no it's not easy to do (it took me a while to get my head around how to assemble the vertex array).  Your keywords are: glVertexArrayBindingDivisor and glDrawElementsInstanced.  Note you may not want instancing (single draw call) and I suspect it doesn't work for that if the meshes are all different, but it will allow you to use a single vbo with different transform matrices.

Comment: Vertices are not processed in sequence, so each vertex should specify by itself to which mesh it belongs. This coukd be an int which you use to index into an array of transformation matrices.

Comment: Either just use a draw call per mesh - or think of it like bones.

Comment: @TomTsagk: VBOs are not means as "object mesh stores", but as large hunks of memory you fill with smaller subregions of data.

Comment: @Mastrem: You're right in not trying to have a lot of small VBOs.

Comment: If you could, they wouldn't be uniform anymore, would they? ;) D3D calls the same concept "constant buffers."

Answer (score 7):

> Can you modify a uniform from within the shader?

If you could, it wouldn't be *uniform* anymore, would it?

Furthermore, what you're wanting to do cannot be done even with Image Load/Store or SSBOs, both of which allow shaders to write data. It won't work because vertex shader invocations are not required to be executed *sequentially*. Many happen at the same time, and there's no way for any shader invocation to know that it will happen "after" the "first vertex" in a mesh.

The simplest way to deal with this is the obvious solution. Render each mesh individually, but set the uniforms for each mesh before each draw call. Without changing buffers between draws, of course. Uniform changes, while not exactly cheap, aren't the most expensive state changes that exist.

There are more complicated drawing methods that could allow you more performance. But that form is adequate for most needs. You've already done the hard part: you removed the need for any state change (textures, buffers, vertex formats, etc) except uniform state.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to minimize draw calls - instancing and batching. The first (instancing) allows you to draw multiple copies of same meshes in one draw call, but it depends on the API (is available from OpenGL 3.1). Batching is similar to instancing but allows you to draw different meshes. Both of these approaches have restrictions - meshes should be with the same materials and shaders.

If you would to draw different meshes in one VBO then instancing is not an option. So, batching requires keeping all meshes in 'big' VBO with applied world transform. It not a problem with static meshes, but have some discomfort with animated. I give you some pseudocode with batching implementation

```
struct SGeometry
{
    uint64_t offsetVB;
    uint64_t offsetIB;
    uint64_t sizeVB;
    uint64_t sizeIB;

    glm::mat4 oldTransform;
    glm::mat4 transform;
}
std::vector<SGeometry> cachedGeometries;

...


void CommitInstances()
{
    uint64_t vertexOffset = 0;
    uint64_t indexOffset = 0;

    for (auto instance in allInstances)
    {
        Copy(instance->Vertexes(), VBO);

        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < instances->Indices().size(); ++i)
        {
            auto index = instances->Indices()[i];
            index += indexOffset;
            IBO[i] = index;
        }

        cachedGeometries.push_back({vertexOffset, indexOffset});

        vertexOffset += instance->Vertexes().size();
        indexOffset += instance->Indices().size();
    }

    Commit(VBO);
    Commit(IBO);
}

void ApplyTransform(glm::mat4 modelMatrix, uint64_t instanceId)
{
    const SGeometry& geom = cachedGeometries[i];

    glm::mat4 inverseOldTransform = glm::inverse(geom.oldTransform);

    VertexStream& stream = VBO->GetStream(Position, geom.offsetVB);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < geom.sizeVB; ++i)
    {
        glm::vec3 pos = stream->Get(i);
        // We need to revert absolute transformation before applying new
        pos = glm::vec3(inverseOldNormalTransform * glm::vec4(pos, 1.0f));
        pos = glm::vec3(normalTransform * glm::vec4(pos, 1.0f));
        stream->Set(i);
    }

    // .. Apply normal transformation
}
```

GPU Gems 2 has a good article about geometry instancing [http://www.amazon.com/GPU-Gems-Programming-High-Performance-General-Purpose/dp/0321335597](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321335597)